# Using Linq to create nested groups and sublists

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a plain table and I'm trying to create a nested group. I then will serialize it to be consumed by my client.

This web site is written in VB.net and I'm having problems understanding linq vb.net

```
Table:
    ╔═══════╦════════╦═══════╦══════╗
    ║ Truck ║ Status ║ Store ║ Stop ║
    ╠═══════╬════════╬═══════╬══════╣
    ║   123 ║ A      ║ NY    ║ A1   ║
    ║   123 ║ A      ║ NY    ║ B1   ║
    ║   123 ║ A      ║ BOS   ║ C1   ║
    ║   456 ║ A      ║ NJ    ║ A1   ║
    ║   456 ║ A      ║ NJ    ║ B1   ║
    ║   222 ║ C      ║ CT    ║ A1   ║
    ║   222 ║ C      ║ CT    ║ B1   ║
    ║   222 ║ C      ║ CT    ║ C1   ║
    ║   222 ║ C      ║ CT    ║ D1   ║
    ╚═══════╩════════╩═══════╩══════╝
```

My linq JSON output should look like

```
[{"Truck":"123","Status":"A","StoreList":[{"Store":"NY","StopCount":"2"},{"Store":"BOS","StopCount":"1"}],"StopsList":[{"Store":"NY","Stop":"A1"},{"Store":"NY","Stop":"B1"},{"Store":"BOS","Stop":"C1"}]},

{"Truck":"456","Status":"A","StoreList":[{"Store":"NJ","StopCount":"2"}],"StopsList":[{"Store":"NJ","Stop":"A1"},{"Store":"NJ","Stop":"B1"}]},

{"Truck":"222","Status":"C","StoreList":[{"Store":"CT","StopCount":"4"}],"StopsList":[{"Store":"CT","Stop":"A1"},{"Store":"CT","Stop":"B1"},{"Store":"CT","Stop":"C1"},{"Store":"CT","Stop":"D1"}]}
]
```

I have been able to do a regular group by not sure how I would go about to do a subgroup and sublist.

In C# I'm able to do a simpel group and a list

```
  var query = queryJoin.GroupBy(x => x.Truck)
                .Select(group => new MainTrailerList
                {
                    Truck = group.Key,
                    Status = group.First().Status,
                    StopsList  = group.Select(a => new TrailerPosition {  Store = a.Store, Stop = a.Stop })
                });

            return Json(query, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

but with Vb.net I need to do nested group and 2 lists.

Comment: you can try some of the online code converters http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: I tried it but did not convert properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you do not want to use Stop as a property name as it is a reserved word in VB.  I used StopDetail instead.

```
queryJoin.GroupBy(Function(t) t.Truck) _
    .Select(Function(t) New MainTrailerList With {
        .Truck = t.Key,
        .Status = t.First().Status,
        .StopsList = t.Select(Function(s) new TrailerPosition with {
            .Store = s.Store,
            .StopDetail = s.StopDetail})})
```

Comment: Note that you can use `Stop` as the property name as long as you escape it with square brackets (e.g. `[Stop]`)